# Setting [no_vars] theory-wide

Tags: presentation, isabelle

I have an Isabelle theory that collects all my results and only presents them, so I’d currently apply `[no_vars]` to all my `@thm` antiquotations. (This suppresses the question marks in the schematic variables which are undesirable in the final presentation.)

Is there a way to make Isabelle use `no_vars` once for the whole theory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the canonical way (whatever that means) is to add such options to your session `ROOT`. Either globally, e.g.,

```
session A = B +
  options [show_question_marks = false]
  theories
    ...
```

or per theory, e.g.,

```
session A = B +
  theories [show_question_marks = false]
    T1
  theories
    T2
    ...
```

Comment: Using `declare [[show_question_marks = false]]` as Joachim did, does it apply locally or to all theories importing the theory declaring this attribute?

Comment: @chris, in my case that is not desired: I want my regular theories printed vanilla style; just one theory has all the syntax sugar enabled.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: I don't get it. With the above you can set it also per theory, not only globally.

Comment: @Hibou57: If the theory that contains the `declare` statement is included in another, also the other one will not have question marks. In that sense, the variant I showed above is more flexible (you can just activate/disable some setting for a specific theory without influencing later ones).

Comment: @chris: One downside of your approach: I need to explicitly list all descendants of `T1` in the second list of theories (where I want the default settings). And given that I configure other output syntax (like translations) in the theory file itself, I prefer this one there as well.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: Right!.

Answer (score 2):

The magic invocation is

```
declare [[show_question_marks = false]]
```

as documented in the section “Details of printed output” in [isar-ref.pdf](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf).